# How can I set the Text to a DropDownList using jQuery in .NET

Tags: jquery, .net

A text holding a value like "Example" and I want this text to added to the empty drop down using jQuery and the drop down should be disabled.

This is not working - `$('#<%=ddlexm.ClientID %>').text("Example")`

Anyone there to help me

Comment: `$('#<%=ddlexm.ClientID %>').append('<option>Example</option>').prop('disabled', true)`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
$('#<%=ddlPO.ClientID %>').append($("<option></option>").val($('#<%=YourTextBoxId.ClientID %>').val()).html($('#<%=YourTextBoxId.ClientID %>').val()).prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: If I want to assign a Value and Text for an empty drop down, How can I do that.

Comment: @Sideways not getting you, please explain in detail